# SQL query for joining two tables and pulling repeated entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to join two tables that handle customer purchases, or purchase-intents in order to figure out how many customers made a repeat purchase-intent.

Posting a stripped down version of the DB schema for the problem:

Bid

- id
- user_id
- created_at

Order

- id
- bid_id (optional)
- user_id
- created_at

User

- id
- created_at

Bids signify purchase intent, while Orders signify purchases. A user could be associated with many Bids or Orders.

So a user can start with
- creating a Bid, which could then become fulfilled, and generates a Order, or
- the user could create an Order without an associating Bid.

Bids aren't directly associated with Orders because a Bid could generate many Orders (one to many).

I'm trying to write a SQL query that pulls users who first created a Bid which became a purchase (i.e have an Order record with a bid_id), and then created another Bid after that.

In English, customers who created a Bid, had the Bid fulfilled, and then placed a new Bid sometime after.

Currently not particular about whether they made a direct purchase (Order without Bid), or had an unfulfilled Bid in between the fulfilled Bid and the new Bid.

Main metric I'm trying to confirm is that they placed a new bid sometime after one of their prior bids got fulfilled.

In trying to solve this, I've been only able to get a list of users who placed more than one bid and had at least one fulfilled. But been unable to get the number of repeat users who first had a prior Bid fulfilled before placing a new bid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exists` comes to mind for this type of query:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where bid_id is not null and
      exists (select 1
              from bids b
              where b.user_id = o.user_id and b.created_at > o.created_at
             );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Totally forgot about exists. Updating the query to 
`select count(distinct(o.user_id))` gave the number of repeat customers